# Apache 2 Setup Subdomain using VirtualHost only works locally

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, subdomain

I'm aware that there are already questions like this, but those did not help.

I am running apache2 on debian 7 and I can access my site locally through `192.168.1.x` and others can access it by my IP address. Now what I want to do is add a subdomain name, so they can access a certain folder like this: `subdomain.myip`. Here is what I currently have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName username.localhost
        ServerAdmin username@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/username/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/username/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The only way I can access it at the moment is by going to username.localhost on debian itself. How can I make it so I can locally access it using `username.192.168.1.x` and others by `username.myip`?

Comment: Your IP isn't a domain, so it can't have subdomains (or at least not ones that are resolved by normal dns servers). You need to buy a domain in order to define subdomains.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499467/how-to-access-the-subdomain-of-an-ip-address-in-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change *username.localhost* in *ServerName* to something else. Localhost is a standart name for ip address 127.0.0.1 which means [this PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). So, if someone tries to use *username.localhost* to access your website, he will try to search it on his own computer instead of yours. In fact this definition between localhost and 127.0.0.1 is written in [*hosts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file.
Second thing - You can't mix ip address and domain name together like *username.192.168.1.x*. You need use either domain name (like username.example.net) or just ip (192.168.1.x).

If you want to stick with domain name then you need either a domain name server or to modify mentioned above *hosts* file on every pc that should access you website add this string:

```
192.168.1.x    username.example.net
```

After that use username.example.net to access your site.

PS: Don't forget to check that firewall on your server is not blocking tcp port 80

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I want people to be able to access username.myip if possible, I will buy a domain for that later. I've set it up like this `ServerName username.myip` and in the hosts as `192.168.1.x username.myip` (where x is the number I use, and myip my ip). This all without scucess though, I can't get someone to visit username.myip, though they can visit myip. I'm sorry if I'm missing something or sound stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: That's because you can not mix ip address and subdomain together. You can use something like _http://192.168.1.x/username_ however.